# domain resolves old ip on win 7

Tags: windows-7, cache

I recently have moved my server and changed nameservers and ip, i updated my domain. but somehow in windows 7 when i go to my domain, it resolves old ip even though mac os x shows the new site. Then i edited hosts file with the new ip in windows, it is ok now. but why this happens ?

is it about isp cache or sth ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could have several reasons!

First of all, restore your hosts files before attempting! ;)

1. You're behind a proxy or router that caches DNS data, try clearing the proxy cache.
2. Try clearing your DNS cache, go to start > execute > type "cmd" and do the following:

   `ipconfig /flushdns`
3. Your browser caches DNS data, depending on your browser, clear the cache.

Comment: i already tried these steps thx

Comment: Tried clearing the browser too? Check here if the domain points to the right IP: http://domaintoip.com/ip.php

Comment: oh ok it is now working, thx man

Comment: You're very welcome ;)